Why is my Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 laptop's brightness broken after reopening the lid?
I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 laptop running Windows 11. My power settings indicate that nothing should happen when I close the lid. Sometimes after the lid is closed for a while and I reopen it with the laptop plugged in the whole time, the screen brightness is broken and requires a restart. The faulty behavior goes like this:

I notice the screen is a little dimmer than it should be
I try pressing the brightness up button on my keyboard and instead of getting brighter the screen gets darker
I try pressing the brightness down button on my keyboard and the brightness drops to 0 almost immediately
I try pressing the brightness up button on my keyboard again and the screen gets a little brighter but the effect is weaker with each press and it approaches an asymptote of about 25% brightness, as though the change in brightness is divided by the current brightness
If I try using the brightness slider in Windows instead of the buttons on my keyboard, I can slide it all the way to 100% but it still looks a little dimmer than it should be
I can fix the problem by restarting the laptop

Since the laptop hasn't gone to sleep when this happens, perhaps it's triggered by opening the lid when the laptop is about to go to sleep. Does anyone have an explanation for and especially a solution to this problem?

It sounds like an OEM driver issue for whatever driver handles keyboard hot keys (e.g. on Alienware, it’s the OSD driver), possibly the GPU driver. Have you tried reinstalling either driver? Have you ever clean installed Windows on the machine and not immediately installed the CPU chipset driver once out of OOBE, prior to installing any other drivers, software, or Windows Updates?

I haven't tried reinstalling the drivers yet and I haven't done the other thing
